# Apache2.4: Service is already installed

Tags: php, apache

Estou tentando instalar dois serviços de apache2.4 só que com portas de diferentes, 64 e 32 bits respectivamente.

Os dois usando o php7

O apache2.4 de 64 bits está instalado. Como pensei que fosse por causa arquitetura baixei a versão 32 bits para tentar instalar

Já modifiquei a porta do segundo apache para:

```
Listen 82
```

Só que um é 64 e outro 32 bits

Ao executar o comando `httpd -k install –n “Nome do Serviço”` do último, ele dá a seguinte mensagem:

> E:\webserver_82\Apache24\bin>httpd -k install -n "Apache PHP7.3 82"
>   [Thu Jan 17 09:43:51.133159 2019] [mpm_winnt:error] [pid 876:tid 172]
>   AH00433: **Apache2.4: Service is already installed**.

No windows 10 local está instalado esses dois, eu gostaria de fazer no servidor que é **Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard**

Existe alguma forma de instalar mais de um serviço com portas diferentes?